# Article needed before a countable noun?

Tags: articles

I have a question about articles.  I came across this sentence below:

> **Although Jesus himself may be perceived as heir to the legacy of Amos and Jeremiah, the Gospels present him as more than a prophet**.

The author did not use an article before the word “heir”. I would add either an article of "an" or "the" before heir. People sometimes skip the article when they speak. For example: somebody called up the doctor of his father and asked:

> **I am son of John, how is he doing?**

In the above example, I think we can skip an article before the word “son”, as it doesn't matter if John has one or more sons in this context.

But in writing, as in the example above regarding heir, I believe an article is necessary.  What do you think?

(This question was inspired by [Can we skip using articles in some sentences?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/192339/91457)).

Comment: It's just normal English not to include the *optional* article in such contexts. Same as saying / writing [Jesus was king of the Jews](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22jesus+was+king+of+the+jews%22), for example. We don't have to say He was ***the*** king or ***the*** heir to some legacy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A full answer that explained when an article is optional might be helpful here.

Comment: Point taken. But I'm assuming I'll be able to find at least one obvious duplicate when I have a look in a minute (just waiting for my tea to brew first! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn’t “king” have an article in “The lion is king of the jungle”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/225314/why-doesn-t-king-have-an-article-in-the-lion-is-king-of-the-jungle) See also ["He is king" vs "He is a king."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124152/he-is-king-vs-he-is-a-king)

Comment: You ***can't*** idiomatically omit the article in your example phone call asking after your father John:  *I am son of John, how is he doing?* But although it's not actually *true*, it's perfectly idiomatic to say *Emperor John Joseph, [**son of John** the Baptist and Mary Magdalene](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22son+of+john+the+baptist%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AJOqlzV7cweh_9UvVsOzwxh9-8bm8-Ntxg:1674839694863&source=lnt&tbs=bkv:p&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsoMWIoOj8AhXNTEEAHXFECZ84ChCnBXoECAEQFQ&biw=1112&bih=526&dpr=3.33), was an important character in history*.

Comment: Thanks Fumble.  I understand your point if we put "king of the Jews", "king of the jungle", and "heir of Amos and Jeremiah" in the same category.  Since "heir of Amos and Jeremiah" is not really an everyday phrase, I have difficulty understanding when an article is optional before a countable noun.  For example, in "I gave Johnny an apple," or "He is a friend of mine," I don't believe the article is grammatically optional.  Has it something to do with words like heir, descendant, son, daughter, etc. ?  Thanks!

Comment: @Gramma-PS I think it s more the verb being used. "*A is B*" can often omit an article, but "*I gave A a B*" usually requires one. I am not sure enough yet of the parameters here to make this an answer.

Comment: Where did you come across that sentence? Please [cite your sources](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source)!

Answer (score 0):

The word "heir" can be used with an article or without.

> Prince William is **the heir** to the throne of the United Kingdom.

> Prince William is **heir** to the throne of the United Kingdom.

As [Colin Fine](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/1780/colin-fine) pointed out in a comment, this same pattern holds true for many nouns that describe **roles or positions of power**:

> Bob is **chairman** of the school board.

> Mary is **captain** of this ship.

> Bill Gates was **CEO** of Microsoft for many years.

> Louis XIV became **king** of France in 1661.

The use of "heir" without an article dates back at least as far as Shakespeare:

> To be or not to be—that is the question:
> Whether ’tis nobler in the mind to suffer
> The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,
> Or to take arms against a sea of troubles
> And, by opposing, end them. To die, to sleep—
> No more—and by a sleep to say we end
> The heartache and the thousand natural shocks
> **That flesh is heir to**—’tis a consummation
> Devoutly to be wished.

<sup>—*Hamlet*, Act 3, scene 1</sup>

If an article was needed, then Shakespeare would have written "that flesh is *the* heir to". But he didn't.

---

You **cannot** say:

> I am son of John.

> I'm son of John.

Native speakers do **not** omit the the article in those sentences.

"I'm the son of John" and "I'm a son of John" are both technically correct, but not widely used.

In almost every case, a native speaker would use a possessive instead:

> I'm John's son.

There is *one* special case where you can use "son of" without an article. If you are an character in a story set hundreds of years ago, you might introduce yourself by listing your ancestry:

> I am Robert, son of John, son of Henry, son of ...

But nobody talks like that in the modern day.

Comment: _Heir_, though we would not normally think of it as a role, is like other words denoting roles, especially after "as". _As president_, _as chair_, _as captain_, _as judge_, _as (legal) counsel_, _as councillor_, _as assistant to the principal_.

Comment: @ColinFine: Excellent point. I've updated my answer accordingly.